# How to read a TAF report which looks like the following?

Tags: weather

How to read a TAF report which looks like this:

TAF: VOBL 010800Z 0109/0118 09005KT 6000 SCT010 BKN080 TEMPO 0109/0118 3000 RA/DZ SCT007 SCT012 FEW025CB OVC080

Comment: What's your specific question? How to interpret the codes, or is there a code you do not understand?

Comment: http://www.flightutilities.com/MRonline.aspx

Comment: You should make basic research on [how to read a TAF report](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_aerodrome_forecast) and then precise what is unclear in this given TAF

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can find [how to decode TAF](https://www.aviationweather.gov/static/help/taf-decode.php#Forecast) at aviationweather.gov site.

A TAF report usually contains the following sequence of elements:

- Type of Report
- ICAO Station Identifier
- Date and Time of Origin
- Valid Period Date and Time
- Forecast Meteorological Conditions

TAF- Type of report

VOBL- ICAO station identifier

010800Z- Date and time of origin

0109/0118- Valid period date and time

09005KT- Wind

6000- Visibility in metres

SCT010 BKN080- Thousand scattered, ceiling eight thousand broken cumulonimbus clouds

TEMPO - Is used to denote temporary conditions which may arise, followed by the forecasted meteorological conditions.

0109/0118- between these times

3000- Visibility in metres

SCT007 SCT012- Same as above